# VS 2015 Find and replace this string but not that string

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I am using VS regex to try and delete the string Windows.Forms but not System.Windows.Forms

I can use this to find all of the lines:

^(?!.*System.Windows.Forms).*Windows.Forms.*$

But I cant use a replace for that since it obviously deletes the whole line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to adjust the lookbehind to

```
(?<!System\.)Windows\.Forms
```

Or with word boundary to be more precise:

```
(?<!\bSystem\.)\bWindows\.Forms\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5CbSystem%5C.)%5CbWindows%5C.Forms%5Cb&i=I%20am%20using%20VS%20regex%20to%20try%20and%20delete%20the%20string%20Windows.Forms%20but%20not%20System.Windows.Forms&r=)

The lookbehind is checking the text *before* the current position meets some subpattern. So, the text you need to match and consume is `Windows.Forms`, but it should not be preceded with `System.`. Thus, the lookbehind (negative one) should only contain `System\.` (or `\bSystem\.`).

Note that the dots must be escaped to match literal dots.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!